# How to Format NSDate in the Model Layer

Tags: core-data, model-view-controller, nsdate

I have a NSDate that I want to return as formatted like 10:00PM.
I have the date formatter working.
I'm wondering how I can make it so that whenever I fetch that date it comes back formatted as desired.
The NSDate in question in a daily start time for an activity that is store in an NSManagedObject 
subclass.

```
@implementation Schedule

@dynamic repeat;
@dynamic start;

-(NSString*)amPMFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.start];
}

@end
```

I'm  using a keypath to fill in a TableViewCell. The object bound to the cell is a Ritual which knows a Schedule. My thought was to call the method amPMFormat using the keypath and just return the formatted date as a string but that doesn't work. This code is a cell created using Sensible TableView. The cell has a STEP bound to it, STEP has a SCHEDULE, and SCHEDULE has a start property which is an NSDate that only has hours and minutes saved into it.

```
SCCustomCell *descrCell = [SCCustomCell cellWithText:nil objectBindingsString:@"1:schedule.start.amPMFormat;3:desc" nibName:@"RitualCell"];
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" how, exactly? And what is that method you're calling in your second code snippet? It's not a standard iOS or OS X method, so what does it do with that string?

Comment: Very cryptic. Use standard methods and modern dot notation such as `label.text = ritual.amPMFormat;`, otherwise your code is incomprehensible.

Comment: Formatting is a view-level concern. You should generally avoid doing this in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've munged the Model and the View parts of your program.

The date (`self.start`) is an instant in time. You can represent that date in any of a multitude of calendars, languages, locale-specific formats, and precision. It's still a single instant in time.

The formatter is a way to build a standard string representation of that instant. If you want the date formatted a particular way "whenever [you] fetch that date", you can use `-awakeFromFetch:` to populate a read-only property. Or perhaps a class method on `Schedule`,  `+formattedStringForDate:`, which formats an `NSDate` appropriately and returns an `NSString`.

Your cryptic second snippet mentions "bindings". Are you using Cocoa Bindings and writing an OS X app? If so, you can put a date formatter on the `NSTextField` instance in your XIB.

Comment: I'm using the Sensible TableView framework to bind the cell values to the model object. The framework uses Cocoa bindings.

Comment: Add an NSDateFormatter to your table cell. That will format the date at the View level, instead of at the Model level.

Comment: I don't know how to get date formatter between the view and the binding but it appears to work using a readonly property on SCHEDULE as you suggested. I can see how this mungs the view and model layer. I used the code posted in my question above.

Comment: Glad it's working. Note that an NSDateFormatter is a rather expensive object to create; consider keeping it as a static, class-level object instead of making/destroying a new one for each Ritual. To use it in Interface Builder, type "NSDateFormatter" into the palette search box, then drag it onto your NSTextField.